# Google Analytics - Track visits from Facebook that end up on specific page

Tags: google-analytics, facebook

My client wants to be able to know how many people come from Facebook to a particular page (promotion landing page) but then proceed to another page (promotion form thank you page). This second page isn't necessarily an exit page.

They'd also like to view this metric as a percentage of all traffic in that behaviour flow.

Currently I have it set up as a custom report with a pageviews metric with the following dimensions as a drilldown list: Landing Page, Second Page, Source, Referral Path. I also have two segments: Source contains "facebook" and Source does not contain "facebook".

I'm just wondering if there's a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

So, you ran a particular campaign on facebook!

Head over to Channel and select Social 
Then Source facebook and chooses Campaign as your Dimension. Select the particular campaign you ran it will tell you how many Sessions/ Users/ Bounce rate and other metrics.

Method one:

Head over to behaviour Flow and select the dimension above Change it from landing page to the campaign and select the specific campaign you want to see. Now, start highlighting the data from the place to the different pages

OR

Now have you created or configured any goals/events for that page.

Goals will be something like this

1. People who visited the page
2. People who click the submit button
3. People who visited the thank you page.